# How to enable AllowOverride in Apache via Puppet Manifest?

Tags: apache, puppet, manifest

If you look at the httpd.conf, you can see 'AllowOverride None',  I want to change this to 'AllowOverride All', but do this via the Puppet manifest below.

I have attempted this with 'directories', but it is not working.  What is the correct way to change AllowOverride to All in this example?

## httpd.conf

```
# ************************************
# Vhost template in module puppetlabs-apache
# Managed by Puppet
# ************************************

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test.example.com
  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/html

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

## apache.pp

```
  apache::vhost { 'test.example.com':
    port        => '443',
    docroot     => '/var/www/html',
    ssl         => true,
    ssl_cert    => "${ssl_base}/ssl.crt",
    ssl_key     => "${ssl_base}/ssl.key",
    directories => [
      {
        'path'          => '/var/www/html',
        'options'       => 'Indexes FollowSymLinks',
        'allowoverride' => 'All',
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the template https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/master/templates/httpd.conf.erb used for that file, the `AllowOverride` value is hardcoded to be `None`. You would need to seek another way of doing the change other than through the `apache` module. You can change the template, use ` file_line`, create a new `file` resource, etc.

Comment: Or, better still, raise a pull request to add the missing feature into the Apache module.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you need to use "allow_override" rather than "allowoverride" or "override" as per the examples given.  This will now create the desired vhost file.

**apache.pp**

```
apache::vhost { 'test.example.com':
  port        => '443',
  docroot     => '/var/www/html',
  ssl         => true,
  ssl_cert    => "${ssl_base}/ssl.crt",
  ssl_key     => "${ssl_base}/ssl.key",
  directories => [
  {
    'path'          => '/var/www/html',
    'options'       => 'Indexes FollowSymLinks',
    'allow_override' => 'All',
  },
],
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the puppet documentation, you would set this with override: 
https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache#override

Here is the template that the apache module uses to set the AllowOverride value:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/61301b5a8d5fa2bf1e98b1d8532aaf141a27f365/templates/vhost/_directories.erb#L55-L57

Your code should look like:

```
apache::vhost { 'test.example.com':
    port        => '443',
    docroot     => '/var/www/html',
    ssl         => true,
    ssl_cert    => "${ssl_base}/ssl.crt",
    ssl_key     => "${ssl_base}/ssl.key",
    directories => [
      {
        'path'          => '/var/www/html',
        'options'       => 'Indexes FollowSymLinks',
        'override' => 'All',
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

Here is an example of how they use override in one of their unit tests:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache/blob/2931d0ebc4a0582e5209e9994ab8ae5c445d87b7/spec/acceptance/vhost_spec.rb#L998-L1015

Answer (score 0):

I used ruby templates for httpd.conf files .

Here , values for allowoverride are passed from hiera based on hierarchy and environment .

If your httpd.conf remains same across environments , you can pass it via file resource method